# Trouble writing OptimizationFunction for automatic forward differentiation during Parameter Estimation of an ODEProblem

Tags: optimization, julia, automatic-differentiation

I am trying to learn Julia for its potential use in parameter estimation. I am interested in estimating kinetic parameters of chemical reactions, which usually involves optimizing reaction parameters with multiple independent batches of experiments. I have successfully optimized a single batch, but need to expand the problem to use many different batches. In developing a sample problem, I am trying to optimize using two toy batches. I know there are probably smarter ways to do this (subject of a future question), but my current workflow involves calling an `ODEProblem` for each batch, calculating its loss against the data, and minimizing the sum of the residuals for the two batches. Unfortunately, I get an error when initiating the optimization with `Optimization.jl`. The current code and error are shown below:

```
using DifferentialEquations, Plots, DiffEqParamEstim
using Optimization, ForwardDiff, OptimizationOptimJL, OptimizationNLopt
using Ipopt, OptimizationGCMAES, Optimisers
using Random

#Experimental data, species B is NOT observed in the data
times  = [0.0, 0.071875, 0.143750, 0.215625, 0.287500, 0.359375, 0.431250,
                      0.503125, 0.575000, 0.646875, 0.718750, 0.790625, 0.862500,
                      0.934375, 1.006250, 1.078125, 1.150000]
A_obs = [1.0, 0.552208, 0.300598, 0.196879, 0.101175, 0.065684, 0.045096,
                      0.028880, 0.018433, 0.011509, 0.006215, 0.004278, 0.002698,
                      0.001944, 0.001116, 0.000732, 0.000426]
C_obs = [0.0, 0.187768, 0.262406, 0.350412, 0.325110, 0.367181, 0.348264,
                      0.325085, 0.355673, 0.361805, 0.363117, 0.327266, 0.330211,
                      0.385798, 0.358132, 0.380497, 0.383051]
P_obs = [0.0, 0.117684, 0.175074, 0.236679, 0.234442, 0.270303, 0.272637,
                      0.274075, 0.278981, 0.297151, 0.297797, 0.298722, 0.326645,
                      0.303198, 0.277822, 0.284194, 0.301471]

                      
#Create additional data sets for a multi data set optimization
#Simple noise added to data for testing
times_2 = times[2:end] .+ rand(range(-0.05,0.05,100))
P_obs_2 = P_obs[2:end] .+ rand(range(-0.05,0.05,100))
A_obs_2 = A_obs[2:end].+ rand(range(-0.05,0.05,100))
C_obs_2 = C_obs[2:end].+ rand(range(-0.05,0.05,100))


#ki = [2.78E+00, 1.00E-09, 1.97E-01, 3.04E+00, 2.15E+00, 5.27E-01] #Target optimized parameters
ki = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1] #Initial guess of parameters
IC = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] #Initial condition for each species
tspan1 = (minimum(times),maximum(times)) #tuple timespan of data set 1
tspan2 = (minimum(times_2),maximum(times_2)) #tuple timespan of data set 2

# data =  VectorOfArray([A_obs,C_obs,P_obs])'
data  =  vcat(A_obs',C_obs',P_obs') #Make multidimensional array containing all observed data for dataset1, transpose to match shape of ODEProblem output
data2 = vcat(A_obs_2',C_obs_2',P_obs_2') #Make multidimensional array containing all observed data for dataset2, transpose to match shape of ODEProblem output

#make dictionary containing data, time, and initial conditions
keys1 = ["A","B"]
keys2 = ["time","obs","IC"]
entryA =[times,data,IC]
entryB = [times_2, data2,IC]
nest=[Dict(zip(keys2,entryA)),Dict(zip(keys2,entryB))]
exp_dict = Dict(zip(keys1,nest)) #data dictionary

#rate equations in power law form r = k [A][B]
function rxn(x, k) 
    A = x[1]
    B = x[2]
    C = x[3]
    P = x[4]
    
    k1 = k[1]
    k2 = k[2]
    k3 = k[3]
    k4 = k[4]
    k5 = k[5]
    k6 = k[6]
    
    r1 = k1 * A
    r2 = k2 * A * B
    r3 = k3 * C * B
    r4 = k4 * A
    r5 = k5 * A
    r6 = k6 * A * B
    
    return [r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6] #returns reaction rate of each equation
end
#Mass balance differential equations
function mass_balances(di,x,args,t) 
        k = args
        r = rxn(x, k)
        di[1] = - r[1] - r[2] - r[4] - r[5] - r[6] #Species A
        di[2] = + r[1] - r[2] - r[3] - r[6]        #Species B
        di[3] = + r[2] - r[3] + r[4]               #Species C
        di[4] = + r[3] + r[5] + r[6]               #Species P

end

function ODESols(time,uo,parms)
    time_init = (minimum(time),maximum(time))
    prob = ODEProblem(mass_balances,uo,time_init,parms)
    sol = solve(prob, Tsit5(), reltol=1e-8, abstol=1e-8,save_idxs = [1,3,4],saveat=time) #Integrate prob
    return sol
end

function cost_function(data_dict,parms)
    res_dict = Dict(zip(keys(data_dict),[0.0,0.0]))
    for key in keys(data_dict)
        pred = ODESols(data_dict[key]["time"],data_dict[key]["IC"],parms)
        loss = L2Loss(data_dict[key]["time"],data_dict[key]["obs"])
        err = loss(pred)
        res_dict[key] = err
    end 
    residual = sum(res_dict[key] for key in keys(res_dict))
    @show typeof(residual)
    return residual
end

lb = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]         #parameter lower bounds
ub = [10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0]   #parameter upper bounds

optfun = Optimization.OptimizationFunction(cost_function,Optimization.AutoForwardDiff())
optprob = Optimization.OptimizationProblem(optfun,exp_dict, ki,lb=lb,ub=ub,reltol=1E-8) #Set up optimization problem
optsol=solve(optprob, BFGS(),maxiters=10000) #Solve optimization problem

println(optsol.u) #print solution
```

when I call `optsol` I get the error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching ForwardDiff.GradientConfig(::Optimization.var"#89#106"{OptimizationFunction{true, Optimization.AutoForwardDiff{nothing}, typeof(cost_function), Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, typeof(SciMLBase.DEFAULT_OBSERVED_NO_TIME), Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing}, Vector{Float64}}, ::Dict{String, Dict{String, Array{Float64}}}, ::ForwardDiff.Chunk{2})
```

Searching online suggests that the issue may be that my `cost_function` function is not generic enough for ForwardDiff to handle, however I am not sure how to identify where the issue is in this function, or whether it is related to the functions (`mass_balances` and `rxn`) that are called within `cost_function`. Another potential issue is that I am not calling the functions appropriately when building the OptimizationFunction or the OpptimizationProblem, but I cannot identify the issue here either.

Thank you for any suggestions and your help in troubleshooting this application!

Answer (score 0):

`res_dict = Dict(zip(keys(data_dict),[0.0,0.0]))`

This dictionary is declared to the wrong type.

`zerotype = zero(params[1])`
`res_dict = Dict(zip(keys(data_dict),[zerotype ,zerotype]))`

or

`res_dict = Dict(zip(keys(data_dict),zeros(eltype(params),2)))`

Either way, you want your intermediate calculations to match the type of `params` when using `AutoForwardDiff()`.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your feedback. I tried your adjustment to `cost_function` but I get the same error still. May the problem lie in the use of dictionaries to store my data? Not sure if the strings present as keys are messing things up, or if the fact that I have a nested dictionary is posing a problem. I tried changing from `L2Loss` to a hard coded sum of square difference to test and still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the variable type specification suggested by Chris, my model also had an issue with the order of the arguments of `cost_function` and how I passed the arguments to the problem in `optprob`. This solution was shown by Contradict [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/trouble-writing-optimizationfunction-for-automatic-forward-differentiation-during-parameter-estimation-of-an-odeproblem/93439?u=juanmvenegas)